# why proc sql sum function returns count instead of total values?

Tags: sas, sum, proc-sql

I am learning proc sql in SAS. When I use sql sum function, I realize if a comparison operator is added, the output is the count of rows instead of vertical sum. How can I get a vertical sum and what is the mechanism behind the said summation?

```
data apple;
input target;
cards;
0
1
3
5
;
run;

proc sql;
select sum(target ge 3)
from apple;
quit;
```

expected result will be 3+5=8;

actual result is 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proc sql;
select sum(target)
from apple
where target ge 3;
quit;
```

I believe what your code was doing is evaluating (target gt 3) as a boolean expression, so since in SAS TRUE=1 and FALSE=0, the sum function was adding 0,0,1,1.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Craig is actually better, but with *case when else end* you could do what you tried.

```
proc sql;
select sum(case when target ge 3 then target else 0 end)
from apple;
quit;
```

Comment: Thx Lee, your input and Craig's input helped me a lot.